# How do I create a for loop for the sum of numbers?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, sum

"Design and implement an application that will calculate (and then print) the sum, 5 + 10 + 15 + 20. Use a for loop. Create a variable to keep track of the sum."

This is the assignment given to me. I am fairly new to programming and would like some guidance. I am familiar with the structure of a for loop and how they work, I just don't know how to tackle this problem.

I attempted to use a while loop instead but it still doesn't work correctly.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    int i = 0;

    int b = 0;

    while(i < 20)
    {
        b = i + 5;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: `i` is never increased, thus the code never exists the `while` loop.

Comment: Where is your attempt with `for` loop instead? That would be more on-topic of your assignment than this code with the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

here it is as a for loop:

```
   public static void main (String[] args) {

    int b = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i <= 20;i+=5)
    {
        b+=i;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    System.out.println("The total is: " +b);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    int i = 0;
    int b = 0;

    for(i=0;i<=20;i=i+5)        //equal to while(i <= 20)
    {
        b = b+i;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

The loop will run till the value of i is 20. The loop will add each value of i to the variable `b` and increment the value of `i` by 5.

Answer (score 0):

And a slightly different way

```
    int arr [] = {5,10,15,20};
    int b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        b += arr[i];
    }
    System.out.println("The sum is " + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not quite what your instructor wanted but you could recognize this is an arithmetic series and save some computing power below. Note the for loop is unnecessary and merely iterates once to assign the value on the right to the primitive variable x.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        x = 4 / 2 * (5 + 20);

    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Also one more approach, which again, more closely mirrors an arithmetic series:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        x += 5 * i;


    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one does not really follow all the guidance but you can try to impress your teachers by creating an infinite Stream and picking first 4 of them and summing them.

```
int sum = IntStream.iterate(5, i -> i + 5)
  .limit(4)
  .sum();
```

This solution is much easier because you write it declaratively without worrying about the initialization of variables and performing additional checks.